# Cropping two transparent png images using Imagick gives different results

Tags: linux, command-line, imagick

I am having different result when cropping two png files.

Imagick Version using `convert -version`:

- Version: ImageMagick 6.6.5-10 2010-11-26 Q16
- Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
- Features: OpenMP

The two files using `identify`:

- `works.png PNG 1218x610 1218x610+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 755KB 0.000u 0:00.000`
- `doesntwork.png PNG 70x70 70x70+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 1.64KB 0.000u 0:00.000`

I am using this command:

```
convert <original>.png -crop 50x50+0+0 <target>.png
```

The problem is that `works.png` is 100% correct, while `doesntwork.png` is a black square.

Both original images seem to be the same - and do display correctly on `windows 7`.

The images:

`works.png`:

[image]

`doesntwork.png`:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the images so that we can test possible solutions?  Also, I'd recommend `identify -verbose` to get more image info, paying particular attention to the colorspace as I've seen that cause similar problems.

Comment: I have added the images to the original post.

Comment: Sorry, but in what sense are the two original images the same?

Comment: They are both transparent and png format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me using `convert -version`ImageMagick 6.4.0 04/17/08 Q16 (which is the "Current" version under `cygwin`), running via cygwin on Windows XP SP3.

It may be a bug in your particular version of ImageMagick.  The shark `works.png` is a full color image with alpha (4 8-bit channels).  The `doesntwork.png` is a 1-bit black and white image with 8 bits of alpha, and the shading is done by varying the alpha.  That seems to me a rather rare format, so I can imagine a bug slipping into the conversion code.

You might try converting the image to true color first.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the two images posted, this seems like it might be a case of tools doing what they're told instead of what's intended.

Using `-crop 50x50+0+0` on the shark image above gives a completely transparent 50 by 50 image because the 50 by 50 block of pixels in the upper left corner (`+0+0`) of the shark image is completely transparent.  Using `-crop 50x200+0+0` captures the tip of the shark's tail as well.  `-crop 50x50+950+250` gets the eye.

Does all this match your results?

Comment: The shark works fine, it's the other that won't crop. I'd like to find out why the shark works, and the other doesn't. I'll add my cropped results for both images tomorrow.

Comment: Both posted images crop fine with ImageMagick 6.7.6-0 2012-03-26 on my system.  Maybe an upgrade's in order, or maybe Imgur did some conversion that solved the problem (though `identify` info is still the same).